# Javascript date validation for PDF-form

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I've got an PDF-form with required fields.
One field is "Valid from" the other "Date of expiry".

Todays date or earlier must be entered into "Valid from".

I'm new into coding with Javascript. I'm using Adobe Acrobat for creating contracts with required fields.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the JavaScript guide published by Adobe.
It contains examples and detailed instructions on what you can and can't include in a pdf (with regards to JavaScript).

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/acro7jsguide.pdf

If you are going to do this for a lot of documents, please consider using iText.
I can certainly imagine a corporate workflow where you want to generate these kinds of forms automatically and provide all of them with the required validation. In which case doing it by hand is going to be a bottleneck.

For more information about how to do this with iText, have a look at

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-7